# retrieving special characters from database to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a data in my database `'A Plus 18" Stand Fan'` without the single quote. i used nvarchar to save the data as it is, but when i try to retrieve it from the database, the data is returning `'A Plus 18\" Stand Fan'`. I tried using `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` and `HtmlUtility.Html.Decode` also `WebUtility.UrlDecode`.  Can someone help me? thanks!

here is my code where i read the data from the database for comparison. the "Model" is the one i need to fix

```
for (int y = 0; y < dt.Rows.Count; y++)
        {
            model = dt.Rows[y]["ItemModel"].ToString();
            string companys = "";

            companys = dt.Rows[y]["Company"].ToString();



            //getAMS(model, quan);
            Utility a = new Utility();
            string com = a.PO();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(com);
            SqlCommand read = con.CreateCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            string stat = "Delivered";

            string mod = "SELECT SUM(Quantity) as Quantity from vConsumables_Balance where Model ='" + model + "' AND Company = '" + companys + "' AND Status = 'Delivered'";

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                read.CommandText = mod;
                reader = read.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                    quan = reader.GetDecimal(0).ToString();



            }
```

Comment: You should be more specific about how did you get this string. A code fragment would help. In general, special characters in C# strings are escaped (prepended with \). Quote is a special character. Hence it has a backslash in front of it.

Comment: Do you need to compare the strings? Because they should be gone when you show the string

Comment: Share your C# code and part of your view/markup.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the data returned in c#. If you are to output that string, you will not see the slash. ('A Plus 18" Stand Fan')

Comment: I believe when you visualise a string in C# it shows the \" but if you print it to the console you wont see the \

Comment: added my code in the question

Comment: What do you see when you query the same table in SQL Management Studio? Just check whether it is saved in the same way in database. Also the "\" will be displayed in debug mode if you hover over the variable, but like Koenyn mentioned, if you print it should display the string without escape character.

Comment: my databse, it is `A Plus 18" Stand Fan` but when i did the `model = dt.Rows[y]["ItemModel"].ToString();` it shows \"

Comment: Even after you print? I mean what do you get after using Console.WriteLine(["ItemModel"].ToString());

Comment: yes. it still has \" in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code line `string mod = "SELECT SUM(Quantity) as Quantity from vConsumables_Balance where Model ='" + model + "' AND Company = '" + companys + "' AND Status = 'Delivered'";` shows that you are creating SQL queries by concatenating string manually. I assume you did the same when inserting the data into the database and used some tool of your own for escaping some characters.

That is a bad idea. You should change all your queries to parameterized queries. That will help you with other issues you are likely to encounter: formatting of numbers and dates, and it will also provide some protection against SQL injection attacks.

As for the `Status` column, I'd suggest to use an integer value representing an enumeration value instead of a string.